# No write permissions on files created using ng generate in docker container

Tags: docker, angular-cli

I'm working on an Angular CLI project which is running inside a docker container.

When I create a new component using `ng g c name` after a bash into the container, the new files on any modification prompt me to enter the password for my user account to save the changes.

The output of `ls -ld` on the newly created directory is-

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  2 13:41 test2
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

Edit: The following is my docker stack file

```
     version: 3.4  

       services:                            

       package-installer:  
               image: dev-env  
       volumes:  
               - ./:/home/app  
       entrypoint: yarn install  

       client-side-dev-env:  
               image: dev-env  
       volumes:  
           - ./:/home/app  
       ports:  
           - "7000:4200"
```

I use `docker stack deploy` to run docker.

Dockerfile-

```
    FROM node:latest

    RUN curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash

    RUN yarn global add @angular/cli

    RUN ng set --global packageManager=yarn

    ENV CONTAINER_PATH /home/app

    WORKDIR $CONTAINER_PATH

    VOLUME $CONTAINER_PATH

    EXPOSE 4200

    ENTRYPOINT ["ng", "serve", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

An `ls -ld` on the local directory that is mounted in the container when docker runs gives `drwxrwxr-x 6 shiv_saz shiv_saz 4096`
shiv_saz is my user account on my system.

Comment: Looks like it's owned by root; what is your `docker run` command or `docker-compose` file?

Comment: @TJBiddle Have edited the question to incorporate the same. Really sorry for the late response...

Comment: Post your `Dockerfile` as well since you're using a custom image. What are the user permissions of the folder on the host that you're deploying this from? You're using a bind mount; so if you don't own that folder - you'd run into this issue.

Comment: @TJBiddle I have added the dockerfile and the permissions result as well. Does the host directory need to be accessible by the root?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "issue" and I did this solution.

In your `Dockerfile` is important to use the `node` user to make sure that you will have permissions to modify the project once it is created.

```
###################################
## Angular CLI
###################################
FROM node:18.18.0-alpine3.18

ARG ANGULAR_CLI_VERSION=

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@${ANGULAR_CLI_VERSION}

ARG WORKING_DIRECTORY=/app

USER node

WORKDIR ${WORKING_DIRECTORY}
```

The `docker-compose.yml` needs the following configuration.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  ##########################################################
  ## Angular CLI - Utiltiy Container
  ##########################################################
  angular-cli:
    image: angular-cli:18.18.0-alpine3.18
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/angular-cli.dockerfile
      args:
        - ANGULAR_CLI_VERSION=15.2.9
        - WORKING_DIRECTORY=/app
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app:rw
```

You could add a `.dockerignore` file to prevent the copy of some directories and files.

```
node_modules/
.vscode/
.gitignore
README.md
```

With all this you could use `commands` like the following.

```
# Create a new Angular project:
$ docker compose run --rm -it --build angular-cli ng new app --directory ./

# Use ng commands:
$ docker compose run --rm -it --build angular-cli ng generate component header --skip-tests --style none

# Use npm commands:
$ docker compose run --rm -it --build angular-cli npm install @angular/fire
$ docker compose run --rm -it --build angular-cli npm remove @angular/fire

# Install project dependencies:
docker compose run --rm -it --build angular-cli npm install
```